# Can't import code from source folder with mocha even though I'm using babel-register

Tags: mocha.js, babeljs, chai, immutable.js, rollupjs

I'm trying to write some tests for a node.js application that's written using ES6 import syntax, and using rollup.js to concatinate the code into a bundle.

For writing tests, I've created a `test`-folder with code that imports relevant parts from my `src`-folder. I've tried to set the following in my 
`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha ./test/**/*.test.js -r  ./test/test_helper.js",
}
```

This results in the code complaining about import statements within my tests (`Unexpected token import`). When I include babel-register to the test-command (`--require babel-register`), it not longer complains about the import statements inside my test-folder, but it gives the same error for the code in my source folder:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Map } from 'immutable';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
  at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
  ...
```

Below is my `package.json` dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^1.2.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "chai-immutable": "^1.5.4",
  "mocha": "^4.1.0",
  "redux-node-logger": "0.0.3",
  "rollup": "^0.36.0",
  "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.6.1",
  "rollup-plugin-json": "^2.0.2"
},
"dependencies": {
  "immutable": "^3.8.1",
  "mqtt": "^1.9.0",
  "redux": "^3.5.2",
  "redux-immutable": "^3.0.6"
}
```

And here's my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Building the application with rollup works fine.

This is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  format: 'cjs',
  plugins: [ json(), babel() ],
  external: [
    'redux',
    'immutable',
    'mqtt',
    'redux-node-logger',
    'http'
  ],
  dest: 'bundle.js'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS doesn't support ESModule yet ([only experiment from the command line](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/esm.html)). So you need to comvert your ESModule in CJSModule. You can do it  with the [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) plugin

In your .babelrc file :

```
"plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
]
```

If you use babel-register the transformation occurs when the file is required(imported)

**Update**

Try to call `require("babel-register")` as a start point in the `before` function of your tests suite. And ensure your path is correct : you can not import `immutable` in your test files like in your source files, you need to specify the directory `src`. Or instead you could use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) to resolve src as root

Here the `.babelrc` file i use:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["module-resolver", {
            "root": ["./src", "./"]
        }],
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I tried to include your code in my .babelrc, but it still spits out the same error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Well i use it perfectly in my case. Do you perform test on your rollup bundle or on your source files directly? If on bundle, what output format do you use (CJS, ES6...)

Comment: I try to import directly from my source files. I've included my rollup config file if that's of any help.

Comment: Still no dice. I included `require('babel-register');` inside my `test_helper.js` and updated `.babelrc`, and I still got the same error.

Comment: Within my test file i have `import reducer from '../src/reducers/mqtt';`, and within my mqtt.js file I write `import { Map } from 'immutable';`. That's what causes the error. In the same test-file, I also import from immutable (`import { fromJs }  from 'immutable'`), but this doesn't cause any errors.